# Frequency marking on 1960s radio crystal

Tags: rf, identification, radio, crystal, vintage

I found several of these old radio crystals, but they do not seem to have the frequency clearly marked, which I found unusual.

Most other ones I have seen have a model number (e.g. CR-18/U) and the frequency marked explicitly (e.g. 2830 KC), but these crystals simply have the numbers "8909474" marked (with no decimal point).

They are date-stamped on the bottom 1-63 which I presume refers to January 1963.

Besides that, they just have an "RR" on the top, and a marking of "CQB" on the opposite side.

**My question is:** does the marking "8909474" refer to the frequency? My best guess would be: 8909.474 KC. Is this safe to say? Is this a non-standard marking procedure, or were many crystals marked in this way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would try to connect this crystal to an oscillator and to measure the frequency. But it may be difficult to guess the tank capacitors.

Comment: 8909474 could be a supplier part number

Comment: specifying the frequency as 8 909 474 would have an implication, namely, 7 significant digits, i.e., better than 0.1 ppm precision. That is highly unlikely (that's OCXO domain, and not been possible in the 1960s),  so I think it's pretty safe to assume the did not specify the frequency that way. Would be different if it said 8.909M or similar.

Comment: @Uwe if the rest of the radio is still there, there might be no need for guesswork :)

Comment: My sober advice: throw them away and buy new parts for what you need (unless you have a compelling and as yet unspecified reason in this question to use them).

Comment: @Andyaka I duly hope this question is about learning the frequencies the *radios* **used** to operate, not the frequency of an oscillator to be used today. 60 years of aging is not a joke ...

Comment: definitely old , just before the use of ultrasonic "cold welds".  I would have guessed 474 was a date code, 4=Apr and 1974 . Everybody had their own secret codes, just before the cold war. ;) but mainly for traceability QA and load pF and PPM bin codes

Comment: I have a piles of those, except the ones I've kept I know the frequency. I'll have to go through the piles to see if I can find one unlabeled like that. But I don't consider them all that valuable. On the other hand, certain crystals made in WW II (FT-243 CR-6/U) are worth their weight in gold. An 8166.7 KC will exhibit, with an appropriate circuit, exactly 8.1667 MHz even after all these years! Amazing work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a house number. I don't think it's related to the frequency directly.

If you have one of those < $10 Chinese [frequency counter boards](https://www.zl2pd.com/xtalchecker.html), they contain a simple crystal oscillator which would allow  you to measure the frequency.

Otherwise, make a Pierce oscillator with a 74HCU04 and a couple of capacitors (try ~22pF each) and use your bench frequency meter or oscilloscope to measure the frequency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiQXwr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Or just patch it in to any old microcontroller board with HC49 package, it will very likely be a Pierce one too but with everything but the crystal already in place.